Accessing function with the same name outside the local scope
I have a dart file (integers.dart) with the following function:
int max(int a, int b) => a > b ? a : b;

The file also has the following extension, which won't compile:
extension MyIterable on Iterable<int> {       
  int get max => isEmpty ? throw Exception('isEmpty') : reduce(integers.max); 
  // compiler doesn't like either  integers.max or just   max  in the reduce() expression
}


How can I refer to the first function within the extension function when both are in the same file? I realise I can put them in different files, or rename one of the functions, or duplicate the code in an anonymous function but that's not a good solution for me.
I couldn't get the compiler to accept any reference to the outer function within the inner function

Make your integers.dart file import itself with a prefix: import 'integers.dart' as integers;

Thanks James, that works perfectly. I'd never have thought of something so infinitely recursive
